# Unexpected Outcome with Generator Expressions and Any/All

Tags: python, generator, any

I'm having an odd issue with evaluating a generator expression.

My code has a generator expression that tests a few conditions. Let's call it "gen_ex". If I turn it into a list to see the output:

```
print(list(gen_ex))
```

I get this:

```
[False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False]
```

However, when I use any() and all() on it, I get unexpected results.

```
any(gen_ex)
```

return False, while:

```
all(gen_ex)
```

returns True.

Should this be the expected behavior? Or is something weird happening behind the scenes?

Comment: Creating the list exhausts the generator; both `any` and `all` aren't seeing any values to test, and so evaluate vacuously to `False` and `True`, respectively.

Comment: ... is that all you are doing? Because if you do `list(gen_ex)` then the generator is consumed, and is always empty after that, and thus, `any` will always return false and `all` true will always return true on empty iterables... please always post a [mcve] so that we can actually reproduce what you are doing and avoid this needless speculation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generators cannot iterated over multiple times. The first call to `list` consumes all the values.

```
>>> gen_ex = (x for x in (1,2,3))
>>> list(gen_ex)
[1,2,3]
>>> list(gen_ex)
[]
```

As such, both `any` and `all` are seeing an empty sequence of values as well. The return values you see are the base cases:

- `any([])` is `False` because there is no True element in the list (i.e., it is not true that an element in the argument evaluates to `True`)
- `all([])` is `True` because there are no False elements in the list (i.e., it is true that every element in the list is `True`, because there *are* no elements)